# Created classes with the same name. How does this work?

Tags: c#, oop, reference

I am a beginner at C# and am currently learning all about List collections and such. I am wondering how/why the code below works:

I create a list of students:

```
// Create student list
List<Student> ListStudents = new List<Student>();
```

I use a WPF button click event to add a new Student (a class) to this list (the data is gathered from some text boxes):

```
private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    student.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    student.City = txtCity.Text;

    // Add student to list
    ListStudents.Add(student);
}
```

Now all this works fine and I can iterate through the 'ListStudents' list and see all the names I add. However I am wondering how exactly this isn't throwing some errors, as my code repeatedly creates a Student Class named "student" every time I click the button. There could be 20 classes all named "student," yet all their unique information is retained within the ListStudents. These are all in the same namespace.

Forgive me for I am new but I am very much intrigued by this. I understand that Classes are reference types so the "student" class points to a block of memory with the relevant information. Is it the case that each index of ListStudents points to this block of memory, but my class named "student" is only ever pointing to one location, which is the location of the most recently created Student?

Is my implementation above good practice?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the relationship between List<> and the class.
Lists are just pointers to the class.

The name student in your above example is a local variable it only exists in the method it was created in. It will never be referenced again and the name does not get saved in the List<>.

Basically what is happening is an object is created in memory. Then student references / points to that object. Then the list points to that object. Finally when the method ends student goes out of scope and is lost forever.